# Is it possible to have multiple checkboxes in one node in jstree or dynatree?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jstree, dynatree

All,

Is it possible to have multiple checkboxes in one node in jstree or dynatree?

I'm new to asp.net mvc and I’m working on a scenario somewhat similar to this one

chkbox1 USA

> ```
>    chkbox2 AK chkbox3 AZ chkbox4 MO
>    chkbox5 CA chkbox6 MI chkbox7 NY
> ```

chkbox2 UK

When the user clicks the country level checkbox (for ex: chkbox1) and submits the form all the states id's under that country should be posted and saved in the database. When the user selects only couple of states and submits the form those selected states id's only should be posted and saved in the database.

I was thinking of using a tri-state checkbox for this and from my research so far it looks like jsTree or dynaTree would be the best candidates.

However as you notice, I wanted to display multiple checkboxes in one node and I’m not very sure whether I can achieve this using jsTree or dynatree.

It looks like jsTree does not support this out of the box without any workarounds. I may be wrong and please correct me if this can be done (any examples or links would be great). I’m not very sure about dynatree.

Also, I’m looking for suggestions from a usability perspective & performance as well. Since the user can save the form for now and later he may want to edit (remove or add some states).

I don’t expect the number of countries to cross more than 30 and 50 states under each country. All the values are static configurations and can be changed only via an admin user.

The chances are highly remote where a user selects all the countries and the states, however when it happens it is expected to post about 1500 ids from the view to the controller with some other values like the user name, email address and phone number. 
Thanks in advance for the help

P.S: I did some research before posting this question and I don’t happen to see anything related with my scenario. If this has been already discussed I apologize for taking away your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have implemented multiple checkboxes within my jsTree thanks to [jsTreeGrid](https://github.com/deitch/jstree-grid) plugin[image: multiple checkboxes within jstree]

Comment: This plugin seems to be cool and thanks for sharing the screenshot. I will check this out. A quick question before i start to research this, if the no of check boxes varies between each node, is there a way to handle?

Comment: It's completely up to you what you insert in each column. There could be a checkbox, dropdown, link, text or nothing. Up to your code.

Comment: i got the basic stuff working with jstreegrid, thanks for the help Radek.